# getting an error Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, items

Huy! I have some issues in my code:

This is my index.html file:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">diyetSahovatKafe</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                      <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="item in items.data" id="item{{item.id}}">
                          <a href="#">{{item.title}}</a> 
                          <img ng-src="{{ item.image }}" />
                          <button ng-click="addItem(item)">Add Me</button>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      <p>Cart:</p>
                      <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="item in cart">
                          <a href="#">{{item.title}} | Count: {{item.count}}</a> 
                          <a ng-click="deleteItem(item)" class="delete-item">X</a>

                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

End this is my app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

and controller file:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope, items) {

$scope.items = items;
$scope.cart = [];

$scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
    var cart = $scope.cart;
    var match = getMatchedCartItem(item);
    if (match.count > 1) {
      match.count -= 1;
      return;
    }
    cart.splice(cart.indexOf(item), 1);
  }



$scope.addItem = function(item) {
    var match = getMatchedCartItem(item);
    if (match) {
      match.count += 1;
      return;
    }
    var itemToAdd = angular.copy(item);
    itemToAdd.count = 1;
    $scope.cart.push(itemToAdd);
  }


  function getMatchedCartItem(item) {
    return $scope.cart.find(function(itm) {
      return itm.id === item.id
    });

  }

}]);

.factory = ("items", function() {
  var items = {};
  items.data = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Item 1",
    image: "img/item01.jpg"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: "Item 2",
    image: "img/item02.jpg"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    title: "Item 3",
    image: "img/item03.jpg"
  }, {
    id: 4,
    title: "Item 4",
    image: "img/item04.jpg"
  }];
  return items;
});
```

Nothing appears when I run the code, please can you check my code and explain me my mistake, Thanks!

Comment: near the end you have `.factory =`, you have nothing in front of it, that is going to give you a syntax error, should show up above the MainController error in the console.

Comment: You never inject `items` to your controllers dependencies array.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have extra `;` and `=` characters in:

   ```
   }]);  // end of MainController

   .factory = ("items", function() {
   ```
2. You forgot to inject `items` in:

   ```
   app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope, items) {
   ```

That said, I suspect you have another error, that is not visible here, because with what is visible you should get something like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` for writing a dot after the semicolon.